# jQuery - input text attributes not displaying on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to generate input elements for a dynamic form.  For the most part, things are working out well, but I'm having a problem setting the text property of the elements... specifically, the text values don't render on the page, though they appear correct in the elements tab of the console.

For instance...

```
function generateInput(siteNumber, x){

    adult = $("<input/>", {
            type: 'radio',
            id: 'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
            name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
            value: 'adult',
            text: 'Adult'
            });

    juvenile = $("<input/>", {
               type: 'radio',
               id: 'juvenile'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
               name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
               value: 'juvenile',
               text: 'Juvenile'
               });

    return adult.append(juvenile);

};

$(document).on("change", ".number_select", function(){
    siteNumber = $(this).parent().attr('data-site_number');
    numberFound = $(this).val();

    for(x = 1; x <= numberFound; x++){
        this['inputArray' + siteNumber].push(generateInput(siteNumber, x));
     };

     $(this).parent().append(this['inputArray' + siteNumber]);
});
```

Despite the fact that the console displays

```
<input type="radio" id="adult11" name="age1[1]" value="adult">Adult</input>
<input type="radio" id="juvenile11" name="age1[1]" value="juvenile">Juvenile</input>
```

these text elements do not appear on the page - the two radio buttons are there, no text.  I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand why this is happening and what I can do to fix it.  Thanks very much!

EDITING
To adeneo's point, input tags are self-closing, so no dice with .text().  However, I have also tried .prepend()/.append() and similarly, nothing doing...

```
adult = $("<input/>", {
     type: 'radio',
     id: 'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
     name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
     value: 'adult'
     }).prepend('Adult');

juvenile = $("<input/>", {
     type: 'radio',
     id: 'juvenile'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
     name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
     value: 'juvenile'
     }).prepend('Juvenile');
```

Comment: An input is a self closing element, it has no text, only a value, nor does it have a closing tag.

Comment: Good call - also tried .prepend() to no avail - editing question to reflect this.

Comment: As it's a self closing element, you can't prepend or append to it, it can't have children.

Comment: You'll have to add the text to the parent element, for instance wrapping both the input and the text in a span etc.

Comment: Here's how BTW -> **https://jsfiddle.net/gczg61vq/1/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a label with the text you want, then prepend the input to the label element:

```
adult = $("<label>Adult</label>").prepend($("<input/>", {
        type: 'radio',
        id: 'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
        name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
        value: 'adult'});
```

Comment: As a best practice, you should also add the `'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+''` generated id tag as a `for` attribute on the `label`.

Comment: Thank you - for whatever reason, I had to parse it like this -                    adult = $("<input/>", {
                            type: 'radio',
                            id: 'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+'',
                            name: 'age'+siteNumber+'['+x+']',
                            value: 'adult'
                            });
        
                    adultLabel = $("<label/>", {
                                    text: 'Adult',
                                    for: 'adult'+siteNumber+''+x+''
                                }).append(adult);

Comment: Using the syntax that you had prepended the label with an empty text input field.  Any idea why?